# Determining whether a graph is Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

> For $a \geq 1$, determine whether $K_{a,2a,3a}$ or $K_{a,2a,3a+1}$ are
>   Hamiltonian.

I have tried drawing lots of pictures all day but cannot solve the problem. Can someone please help me out with this? I know that there are some results on determining whether a graph is Hamiltonian that are all present in my textbook. For example I know $k(G - S) \leq |S|$  holds for a Hamiltonian graph for every proper set $S$ of vertices.

There are a few other results that I have but I don't  know if they are helpful in this problem.

Note: $K_{a, b, c}$ is the complete tripartite graph on $a + b + c$ vertices.

Comment: Could you spell out here in your Question explicitly which of the two hamiltonian definitions you are using? ==== Also, what is $k$? What is $G$?

Comment: A Hamiltonian graph is a graph that contains a Hamiltonian cycle. $G$ is the graph. $k(\cdot)$ is the number of components of a graph (so $G$ is connected if $k(G) = 1)$. The result I cited is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991819/prove-that-if-g-has-a-hamiltonian-path-then-kg-s%E2%89%A4s1-for-every-non-empty

Comment: +! for your comment. And still, to me, a simple graph $G$ is an ordered pair $\,G:=(V\,E),\,$ where $\,E\subseteq\binom V2.$

Answer (score 1):

In the case of $K_{a,2a,3a}$, let the $3$ parts be $U,V,W,$ with $|U|=a, |V|=2a, |W|=3a$.  Arrange the vertices of $W$ in a circle. Between any two of them, place a vertex from $U\cup V$. This construction gives a Hamilton cycle.

In the case of $K_{a,2a,3a+1}$, suppose there is a Hamilton cycle.  Let the parts be $U,V,W,$ with $|U|=a$, $|V|=2a$, $|W|=3a+1$.  In the cycle, each vertex from $W$ is adjacent to $2$ vertices from $U\cup V$, giving $6a+2$ vertices in $U\cup V$.  Each vertex in $U\cup V$ is counted at most twice, so there are at least $3a+1$ vertices in $U\cup V$, contradiction.

Comment: To phrase the  second part slightly differently, $k(G-(U\cup V))=|W|=3a+1>|U\cup V|$

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe Thanks for the comment, but I don't know what it means. I know this was in the question, but I didn't understand it there either.  Is $k$ the number of components?  Does this theorem have a name?

Comment: @saulplatz A necessary condition for a graph to have a Hamilton cycle is that for any subset $S\subseteq G$ the number of components of $G-S$ is at most $|S|$. (If you mark the vertices of $S$ on the cycle then  there's a vertex of $S$ between visits to the different components.) redblacktrees links to a relevant post in their comment above. Your answer  (roughly) reproves this result in the case you're considering.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe Thanks again for the explanation.